# If $H\leq K\leq G$, $H$ is characteristic in $G$, then is $H$ characteristic in $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H\leq K\leq G$, $H$ char $G$, then is it true that $H$ char $K$?

I don't think that every automorphism $\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}K$ can be extended to $\overline\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}G$, so I guess this may not be true. But I'm not really good at finding counterexamples... Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: There are counterexamples of order $8$ with $|H|=2$ and $|K|=4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think you comment should be an answer so that I can accept it. :) And sorry for asking a stupid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is the abelian group $C_4 \times C_2 = \langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$, with $|x|=4$ and $|y|=2$.

Let $H = \langle x^2 \rangle$. Then $H = \{ g^2 : g \in G \}$ and so is characteristic in $G$.

Let $K = \langle x^2,y\rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2$. Then there is an automorphism of $K$ fixing $y$ and interchanging $x^2$ with $x^2y$, so $H$ is not characteristic in $K$.

There is a similar counterexample with $G$ equal to the dihedral group of order $8$.